# few multiple choice question on continuity

Tags: real-analysis

which of the following statements are true

1. let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\sin x^3$. then $f$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.
2. every differentiable function $f:(0,1)\to[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous.
3. $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map between metric spaces. if $f$ is a bijection, then its inverse is also continuous.

my thoughts:

1. **true** as its derivative is unbounded.
2. **false** example is $x^2\sin(1/x)$.
3. **false**.

please somebody confirm me about my thinkings. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conclusions are correct, but you haven't given correct reasons.

1. There are uniformly continuous functions with unbounded derivatives, like $\sqrt[3]{x}$.  (There are also examples where the derivative is everywhere defined.)
2. That example is uniformly continuous.
3. Can you think of an example?

Comment: can u suggest me proper counter example or proofs for the problem.

Comment: for 3 i think x=1-x do the job

Comment: @poton: I don't understand your last comment.  For (3) I recommend wrapping a half-open interval around a circle.  For (1) I recommend showing that $\sqrt[3]{n\pi}$ and $\sqrt[3]{n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$ get arbitrarily close as $n$ increases, but applying $f$ at these points gives outputs $1$ apart.  For (2) I recommend choosing an example that does not have a limit at $0$.